# Does a list of all known target triplets in use exist?

Tags: compiler-construction, cross-compiling, autoconf

When cross compiling tools, you will often have to provide "a target triplet". Example given

- i686-pc-linux-gnu
- arm-none-linux-gnueabi
- powerpc-unknown-linux

and so on...

These triplets, which are sometimes in fact four components, have the following form:

`<CPU>-<MANUFACTURER>[-<KERNEL>]-<OS>`

Kernel is optional and manufacturer can be something like "unknown" or "none", since it is often not relevant.

What I haven't found yet is a page that documents all possible values to be used here. I know that all components are pretty much "free style", so there is no official standard that would force you to use components from an official standardized list. Yet tool designers and configure script writers expect users to specify those triplets to their tools/scripts, so they must have some possible values in mind and there ought to be something like an "unofficial list" tool makers, script writers and users can use as a reference.

Has anyone ever found such a list?

Comment: The [`config.sub` source code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/config.git/tree/config.sub) is the "official" list when the GNU build tools invented the thing. However, various compiler vendors and OS developers extend the list in their own way and ultimately there is no formal standard on how the triplets should be named.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a useful list, courtesy of `rustc --print target-list`:

```
aarch64-apple-darwin
aarch64-apple-ios
aarch64-apple-ios-macabi
aarch64-apple-ios-sim
aarch64-apple-tvos
aarch64-apple-watchos-sim
aarch64-fuchsia
aarch64-kmc-solid_asp3
aarch64-linux-android
aarch64-nintendo-switch-freestanding
aarch64-pc-windows-gnullvm
aarch64-pc-windows-msvc
aarch64-unknown-freebsd
aarch64-unknown-fuchsia
aarch64-unknown-hermit
aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu_ilp32
aarch64-unknown-linux-musl
aarch64-unknown-netbsd
aarch64-unknown-none
aarch64-unknown-none-softfloat
aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx710
aarch64-unknown-openbsd
aarch64-unknown-redox
aarch64-unknown-uefi
aarch64-uwp-windows-msvc
aarch64-wrs-vxworks
aarch64_be-unknown-linux-gnu
aarch64_be-unknown-linux-gnu_ilp32
arm-linux-androideabi
arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi
arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
arm-unknown-linux-musleabi
arm-unknown-linux-musleabihf
arm64_32-apple-watchos
armeb-unknown-linux-gnueabi
armebv7r-none-eabi
armebv7r-none-eabihf
armv4t-none-eabi
armv4t-unknown-linux-gnueabi
armv5te-none-eabi
armv5te-unknown-linux-gnueabi
armv5te-unknown-linux-musleabi
armv5te-unknown-linux-uclibceabi
armv6-unknown-freebsd
armv6-unknown-netbsd-eabihf
armv6k-nintendo-3ds
armv7-apple-ios
armv7-linux-androideabi
armv7-sony-vita-newlibeabihf
armv7-unknown-freebsd
armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabi
armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
armv7-unknown-linux-musleabi
armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf
armv7-unknown-linux-uclibceabi
armv7-unknown-linux-uclibceabihf
armv7-unknown-netbsd-eabihf
armv7-wrs-vxworks-eabihf
armv7a-kmc-solid_asp3-eabi
armv7a-kmc-solid_asp3-eabihf
armv7a-none-eabi
armv7a-none-eabihf
armv7k-apple-watchos
armv7r-none-eabi
armv7r-none-eabihf
armv7s-apple-ios
asmjs-unknown-emscripten
avr-unknown-gnu-atmega328
bpfeb-unknown-none
bpfel-unknown-none
hexagon-unknown-linux-musl
i386-apple-ios
i586-pc-windows-msvc
i586-unknown-linux-gnu
i586-unknown-linux-musl
i686-apple-darwin
i686-linux-android
i686-pc-windows-gnu
i686-pc-windows-msvc
i686-unknown-freebsd
i686-unknown-haiku
i686-unknown-linux-gnu
i686-unknown-linux-musl
i686-unknown-netbsd
i686-unknown-openbsd
i686-unknown-uefi
i686-uwp-windows-gnu
i686-uwp-windows-msvc
i686-wrs-vxworks
m68k-unknown-linux-gnu
mips-unknown-linux-gnu
mips-unknown-linux-musl
mips-unknown-linux-uclibc
mips64-openwrt-linux-musl
mips64-unknown-linux-gnuabi64
mips64-unknown-linux-muslabi64
mips64el-unknown-linux-gnuabi64
mips64el-unknown-linux-muslabi64
mipsel-sony-psp
mipsel-sony-psx
mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu
mipsel-unknown-linux-musl
mipsel-unknown-linux-uclibc
mipsel-unknown-none
mipsisa32r6-unknown-linux-gnu
mipsisa32r6el-unknown-linux-gnu
mipsisa64r6-unknown-linux-gnuabi64
mipsisa64r6el-unknown-linux-gnuabi64
msp430-none-elf
nvptx64-nvidia-cuda
powerpc-unknown-freebsd
powerpc-unknown-linux-gnu
powerpc-unknown-linux-gnuspe
powerpc-unknown-linux-musl
powerpc-unknown-netbsd
powerpc-unknown-openbsd
powerpc-wrs-vxworks
powerpc-wrs-vxworks-spe
powerpc64-ibm-aix
powerpc64-unknown-freebsd
powerpc64-unknown-linux-gnu
powerpc64-unknown-linux-musl
powerpc64-unknown-openbsd
powerpc64-wrs-vxworks
powerpc64le-unknown-freebsd
powerpc64le-unknown-linux-gnu
powerpc64le-unknown-linux-musl
riscv32gc-unknown-linux-gnu
riscv32gc-unknown-linux-musl
riscv32i-unknown-none-elf
riscv32im-unknown-none-elf
riscv32imac-unknown-none-elf
riscv32imac-unknown-xous-elf
riscv32imc-esp-espidf
riscv32imc-unknown-none-elf
riscv64gc-unknown-freebsd
riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu
riscv64gc-unknown-linux-musl
riscv64gc-unknown-none-elf
riscv64gc-unknown-openbsd
riscv64imac-unknown-none-elf
s390x-unknown-linux-gnu
s390x-unknown-linux-musl
sparc-unknown-linux-gnu
sparc64-unknown-linux-gnu
sparc64-unknown-netbsd
sparc64-unknown-openbsd
sparcv9-sun-solaris
thumbv4t-none-eabi
thumbv5te-none-eabi
thumbv6m-none-eabi
thumbv7a-pc-windows-msvc
thumbv7a-uwp-windows-msvc
thumbv7em-none-eabi
thumbv7em-none-eabihf
thumbv7m-none-eabi
thumbv7neon-linux-androideabi
thumbv7neon-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
thumbv7neon-unknown-linux-musleabihf
thumbv8m.base-none-eabi
thumbv8m.main-none-eabi
thumbv8m.main-none-eabihf
wasm32-unknown-emscripten
wasm32-unknown-unknown
wasm32-wasi
wasm64-unknown-unknown
x86_64-apple-darwin
x86_64-apple-ios
x86_64-apple-ios-macabi
x86_64-apple-tvos
x86_64-apple-watchos-sim
x86_64-fortanix-unknown-sgx
x86_64-fuchsia
x86_64-linux-android
x86_64-pc-nto-qnx710
x86_64-pc-solaris
x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
x86_64-pc-windows-gnullvm
x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
x86_64-sun-solaris
x86_64-unknown-dragonfly
x86_64-unknown-freebsd
x86_64-unknown-fuchsia
x86_64-unknown-haiku
x86_64-unknown-hermit
x86_64-unknown-illumos
x86_64-unknown-l4re-uclibc
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnux32
x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
x86_64-unknown-netbsd
x86_64-unknown-none
x86_64-unknown-openbsd
x86_64-unknown-redox
x86_64-unknown-uefi
x86_64-uwp-windows-gnu
x86_64-uwp-windows-msvc
x86_64-wrs-vxworks
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is in the libtool sources. It's called [PLATFORMS](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/libtool.git/tree/doc/PLATFORMS). It's probably not complete. There's also a file called `config.sub` that gets generated when `autoreconf` is run.  Those are probably more up to date/complete.

But by definition, what you are asking for seems kind of impossible. If there's a new 'xyz' CPU that some manufacturer rolls out it's not going to appear on the list for a time.

So what's a `configure` script writer do in that case? My solution is the following.  I have `autoreconf` called in a script called `bootstrap.sh` that sets up a few things before the build as advocated by the [Goat Book](http://www.sourceware.org/autobook/) folks.  This script uses sed (well, technically the sed wrapper script in [GNU shtool](http://www.gnu.org/software/shtool/)) to insert what I need into `config.sub` after `autoreconf` copies it to AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR.

Fortunately, `config.sub` files are timestamped so if/when 'xyz' is added to the "official" list you can just test the timestamp.  Then you'll add the new "official" `config.sub` to your tarball and use `bootstrap.sh` to test if `autoreconf` is writing a recent enough `config.sub`.  If it's not a recent enough, copy over the old one with the new one.

Comment: +1 for the PLATFORMS list, unfortunately it misses ARM completely.

Comment: There is also [llvm::Triple Class Reference](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Triple.html). Not only is ARM listed, so is iOS. It will probably be helpful for Clang. I'm not sure how useful for Linux tools.